# Wordpress on windows with xampp How to change default URL

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, xampp, bitnami

I install wordpress on Windows 7 machine with xampp and bitnami.

By default it's url is `http://127.0.0.1/wordpress`

How could I change it to some standard host name without page prefix (like `http://myworpdress`)

Answer (score 1):

The Bitnami WordPress Stack includes a tool called "bnconfig" that allows you to solve this issue easily. Everything is documented in the Bitnami documentation, please take a look to the link below:

https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/wordpress/#how-to-configure-the-application-to-run-at-the-root-url-of-the-domain

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an entry in your hosts file(C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts) for your domain

```
127.0.0.1    mywordpress
```

and in addition, you could add vhosts in your apache config, if you would test multiple domains on your local machine

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName wordpress

    DocumentRoot C:\yourpath\...
</VirtualHost>
```

The vhost config is located under C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf. NameVirtualHost should also be enabled in the vhosts.conf file

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to create an alias. In this scenario you will still refer to localhost, but you can also permanently have multiple parallel websites on a single server and to locate them wherever you like on your file system.

For example:

- http://localhost/toenails/
- http://localhost/sock_collection/
- etc.

In the DocumentRoot section of the apache httpd.conf file add the following:

```
Alias /toenails/ "C:\projects\toenails/"
<Directory "C:\projects\toenails">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted

</Directory>
```